# Access Outside Database from within Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, connection

I need to access data in an MS SQL database from a rails app.

The MS SQL database is maintained by our contractors, we just need to access data from it.

Is there a way in rails that I can access an outside db (not the main rails db)?

I can write my own SQL queries, I just need to open a connection to that outside db.

I'm on Rails 3.2.1

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Connection Ninja](https://github.com/cherring/connection_ninja) , it's pretty straight forward and easy to use.